# Show that a path $\beta: I \rightarrow B $ lifts to a path $\bar{\beta}: I \rightarrow E .$

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, homotopy-theory, fibration

The question is:

Let $p: E \rightarrow B $ be a fibration. Show that a path $\beta: I \rightarrow B  $ with $\beta(0) = b_{0}$ and $e_{0} \in p^{-1}(b_{0})$ lifts to a path $\bar{\beta}: I \rightarrow E $, i.e., $p \circ \bar{\beta} = \beta,$ with $\bar{\beta} (0) = e_{0}.$

Now, I have read this question [Show that $\phi$ is a fibration.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3448331/show-that-phi-is-a-fibration/3449410#3449410) and I claim that I understand it which means that I understand how to prove that something is a fibration by proving the HLP for it. but still I am unable to answer the question I mentioned above. and I got a **hint** that the proof is by direct application of fibration definition and that we should define a homotopy that gives us something homotopic to a point. 
but still I am unable to write a rigorous and thorough proof for it. so could anyone help me in doing so?

Comment: *By definition* a fibration has the homotopy lifting property (at least wrt CW complexes in the case of a Serre fibration). Then you just need to notice that a path is nothing more that a homotopy between maps from a $1$-point space (which in particular is a $0$-dimensional CW complex).

Comment: @William how did you understand this? based on what pages in AT ?

Comment: A homotopy between two continuous functions $f,g\colon X \to Y$ is a continuous function $H\colon X\times I \to Y$ satisfying blah blah. If $X \cong \ast$ then $X\times I \cong I$ so $H$ is just a continuous function $I \to Y$, i.e. a path. I'm not sure if this is discussed explicitly in Hatcher or just left as an exercise, it would probably either be in the first sections about point-set topology, or wherever he defines fibrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, prove the following:

> 1. A point $x$ of a space $X$ corresponds to a (continuous) function $\mathbf{x} : \ast \to X$ that sends $*$ to $X$.
> 2. Paths $\gamma : I \to X$ from $x$ to $y$ are in bijective correspondence to homotopies $H : \mathbf{x} \simeq \mathbf{y}$ with $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}: \ast \to X$ the functions associated to $x$ and $y$, where $H$ is defined via $H(*,t ) = \gamma(t)$.

From now on I will make an abuse of notation and write $x$ for both a point $x \in X$ and the associated function $\ast \to X$.

Fix a path $\gamma : I \to B$ from $b_0$ to $b_1$. This gives a homotopy $H : b_0 \simeq b_1$. Since $e_0 \in p^{-1}(b_0)$, its associated map $e_0 : \ast \to E$ satisfies

$$
p \circ  e_0 = b_0 = H_0.
$$

Now, as $p$ is a fibration, we have a homotopy $G : \ast \times I \to E$ such that $pG = H$ and $G_0 = e_0$. If we define $\widetilde{\gamma}(t) := G(\ast,t)$, then

$$
\widetilde{\gamma}(0) = G_0(\ast) = e_0(\ast) = e_0 \in E
$$

and

$$
p \circ \widetilde{\gamma}(t) = p \circ G(\ast,t) = H(\ast,t) = \gamma(t).
$$

Comment: And what is the proof for 1 &2, could you include this in your answer or at least point out on what pages of AT they can be found, please?

Comment: One can establish first the bijection $x \mapsto \mathbf{x}(\ast) = x$ at a set level, and the observe that by definition every function $\ast \to X$ is continuous. That proves the first claim.

Comment: As for the second claim, the bijection is given by composing with the homeomorphism $\ast \times I \to I$ given by the canonical projection.

Comment: are you using the idea that a function from one point to a space is just one point so it is continuous?

Comment: do you mean by $*$ the base point?

Comment: for your justification for the second claim, you said "the bijection is given by composing with the ......". my question is: composing what?

Comment: I'm noting $\ast$ for the one point space and its only point (once again this is standard abuse of notation). As for your second question, I meant that given a path $\gamma$, you can consider $H := \gamma \circ p$ with $p: \ast \times I \to I$ the canonical projection. This assignment is bijective between paths from two given points and homotopies of the maps mentioned in the answer.